# SVG Image Bottom Border

Tags: css, svg, border

I would like to add a wavy line to the bottom of a set of images on a site.

I found some code for an SVG image that renders correctly as an image, but when I set an image's border-image property to that SVG, nothing is displayed.

Here is the html:

```
    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' style='fill:blue'
         viewBox='0 0 1440 126' >
<path transform='scale(1, -1) translate(0, -100)'  d='M685.6,38.8C418.7-11.1,170.2,9.9,0,30v96h1440V30C1252.7,52.2,1010,99.4,685.6,38.8z'/>
</svg>">

<img src="data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox='0 0 10 10'  width='48' height='48' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><circle r='50%' cx='50%' cy='50%' fill='none' stroke='purple' stroke-width='5' stroke-dasharray='1 3'/>
<circle r='50%' cx='50%' cy='50%' fill='none' stroke='orangered' stroke-width='5' stroke-dasharray='.8 2.5'/><circle r='50%' cx='50%' cy='50%' fill='none' stroke='gold' stroke-width='5' stroke-dasharray='.6 2'/><circle r='50%' cx='50%' cy='50%' fill='none' stroke='yellowgreen' stroke-width='5' stroke-dasharray='.4 1.5'/><circle r='50%' cx='50%' cy='50%' fill='none' stroke='teal' stroke-width='5' stroke-dasharray='.25 1'/>
            </svg>">

    <div >
        <p>with border that doesn't work</p>
        <img class="box box--4" src="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/img1_0.png">
        <p>  after</p>

         <p>with border that does work</p>
        <img class="box box--3" src="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/img1_0.png">
        <p>  </p>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
div {
  width: 40vw;
  height: 40vh;
  margin: 4em auto;
}

.box--4
{
      width: 300px;
    border: 3rem solid transparent;
    border-top:0;
border-left:0;
border-right:0;
    border-image-width: 20px;
    border-image:  
        url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'  style='fill:blue'
         viewBox='0 0 10 10'   width='48' height='48'   >
<path transform='scale(1, -1) translate(0, -100)'  d='M685.6,38.8C418.7-11.1,170.2,9.9,0,30v96h1440V30C1252.7,52.2,1010,99.4,685.6,38.8z'/>
</svg>") 100%;
}

.box--3
{
      width: 30px;
    border: 3rem solid transparent;
    border-top:0;
border-left:0;
border-right:0;
    border-image:  
        url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox='0 0 10 10'  width='48' height='48' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><circle r='50%' cx='50%' cy='50%' fill='none' stroke='purple' stroke-width='5' stroke-dasharray='1 3'/>
<circle r='50%' cx='50%' cy='50%' fill='none' stroke='orangered' stroke-width='5' stroke-dasharray='.8 2.5'/><circle r='50%' cx='50%' cy='50%' fill='none' stroke='gold' stroke-width='5' stroke-dasharray='.6 2'/><circle r='50%' cx='50%' cy='50%' fill='none' stroke='yellowgreen' stroke-width='5' stroke-dasharray='.4 1.5'/><circle r='50%' cx='50%' cy='50%' fill='none' stroke='teal' stroke-width='5' stroke-dasharray='.25 1'/>
            </svg>") 25%;
}


.box {
    position: relative;
    margin: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
    //height: 13rem;
  //  box-sizing: border-box;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Page styles */

HTML,
BODY {
    height: 100%;
}

BODY {
    display: block;
    align-items: center;
    min-width: 51rem;
    justify-content: center;
    background: linear-gradient( #DDD 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient( 90deg, #DDD 1px, transparent 1px);
    background-color: #fff;
    background-size: 1rem 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    font: 14px/1.4 Tahoma, sans-serif;
}
```

I have a code pen here:

https://codepen.io/roadpost/pen/zYOByqB

The first image is the 'wavy' line svg, which renders correctly.

The second image is the another sample svg, which also renders correctly.

Thanks for any insight that can be shed as to why the box-4 border image displays nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use svg correctly. Using svg with css it's tricky because you need to url encode most of the characters.

`<` replace by `%3C`

`>` replace by `%3E`

`#` replace by `%23`

For complete list of characters check out this [LINK](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

---

This is a template of svg in css:
`background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 512 512' fill='%23' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E    SVG SHAPES HERE    %3C/svg%3E")`

Comment: I don't think you have to url encode, if you use:
    data:image/svg+xml;utf8

The second image displays fine, and works fine for the border, so yes, there is something wrong with the first image.